# Подгрузка скрипта при скролле

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вписать данный скрипт

`<script async src="https://usocial.pro/usocial/usocial.js?v=6.1.4" data-script="usocial" charset="utf-8"></script>`

в код ниже, что бы он подгружался при скролле страницы.

```
<script>
var fired = false;
 
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (fired === false) {
        fired = true;
        
        setTimeout(() => {
                    
???  
        }, 1000)
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, как то так.

```
    var sNode = document.createElement('script');
    sNode.src = 'https://usocial.pro/usocial/usocial.js?v=6.1.4';
    sNode.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(sNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

можно так

```
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.src = "http://www.example.com/my-script.js";
document.body.appendChild(newScript);
```

и так

```js
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
var inlineScript = document.createTextNode("alert('Hello World!');");
newScript.appendChild(inlineScript); 
document.getElementById("div").appendChild(newScript);
```

```html
<div id='div'> </div>
```